# iOS 8 sizeThatFits crash when encountering special characters

Tags: ios, ios8

I have several labels and I use sizeThatFits: to calculate their height according to their text.
It worked very well in iOS7.

However in iOS8, it crashes when the the label text includes some special characters like "**ʕ •ᴥ•ʔ**".

No crash log occurs.

And I found a strange phenomenon. It crashes both on iPhone Simulator and on my device, however if I plug out my device and run the app without using Xcode6, it won't crash!

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Report it as a bug to https://bugreport.apple.com